# How to download packages, Programming R

Tags: r

I have no idea how to open the file of the packages on programming R. For instance, when I download one of the Windows binaries of rgl from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.htm and I select R file of the downloaded zip file,using programming R,  it does not work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to install packages or just look at the contents? If the former (install), you can just `install.packages("rgl")` from an R session (at an R console). If the latter, just unzip in Windows Explorer and look at the contents.

Comment: Though looking at the binaries is probably not very useful. The package source is more interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, when I type install.packages(" plotrix "), it shows; Warning message: package ‘ plotrix ’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2). Should I use another programming R, if so, what type of programming R should I use? (I type wrong word on previous time; "Thank you foe the answer", i am so sorry)

Comment: Try `install.packages( "plotrix" )`, important is no space between quotation marks and `plotrix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R is command-line based. That means that every action taken by R has to be specified in a line of code, including downloading and loading packages.

To download a package, you would use

```
install.packages("packagename")
```

Make sure there are no spaces between the quotation marks and the name, R can be very literal, so for instance " package" is different from "package" as it has an extra space. After you install a package you still cannot use it until you tell R to load it using one of:

```
library(packagename)
require(packagename)
```

Note that quote marks are no longer needed at this point. If this is all so very confusing, might want to give [R Commander](http://www.rcommander.com/) a try.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a fledgling R user and I do not well about this program. You helped me a lot.